# Reactive Extensions Web Server

Tags: c#, webserver, system.reactive

Just out of personal interest, I decided to try to write a basic web server using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) (aka Rx). Almost immediately, I came up against the following problem:

HttpListener's async pattern doesn't match the normal async pattern signature, the EndGetContext returns a HttpListenerContext instead of an IAsyncResult!

So my question is: is there a way around this?

Here's some code - the compiler (rightly) complains about the second argument to Observable.FromAsyncPattern:

**Update** - As Jon rightly pointed out, it wasn't the pattern, it's complaining that I haven't provided the return type - this works:

```
var observable = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<HttpListenerContext>(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext);
```

The original code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RxWebTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            try
            {
                listener.Start();

                var observable = Observable.FromAsyncPattern(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext);



                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *is* the normal pattern. It's [`BeginGetContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext.aspx) which returns `IAsyncResult`; [`EndGetContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.endgetcontext.aspx) *takes* an `IAsyncResult` and returns the result of the asynchronous operation - the context. That's exactly the same as (say) `Stream.BeginRead`/`EndRead`, where `EndRead` returns an `int`, the number of bytes read.

What happens when you try the code you've posted? I can't immediately see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to figuring out the template parameters for FromAsyncPattern, is to imagine you're creating a Func that is matching the *synchronous* version of the function.

In this case, the prototype is:

`public HttpListenerContext GetContext()`

Which means, my Func would look like:

`Func<HttpListenerContext>`

Then, just take your template parameter and copy-paste it to the FromAsyncPattern.